# Meaning of "financial instruments expanded the dimensions over which individuals could come to agreements"

Tags: meaning

Financial markets allow strangers to exchange value through time more efficiently than traditional reciprocity arrangements do. They do not require shared belief systems or cultural norms, simply a structure for documentation and enforcement. Financial instruments expanded the dimensions over which individuals could come to agreements, and this expansion uniquely fits the needs of a complex, multidimensional urban society.

Does it mean people had more ways in which to reach agreements or that they could come to agreements on more things?

Comment: The answer seems to be found in changing (i) "expanded the dimensions over which" for "increased the variety of circumstances in which", and (ii) "multidimensional urban society" for "a more complex, city-based, society [as opposed to a simpler agrarian/industrial society]."

Comment: The critical word is "dimensions".  You have to understand its meaning in this context.

Comment: The question calls for interpretation of one specific text; answering it is unlikely to illuminate any general feature of the language.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is a reference to the first sentence, which includes "exchange value through time". The implication of "expanded the dimensions" would be that instead of being confined to the present, with a simple exchange of goods for money or more goods, financial instruments have allowed people to bet on projections of value into the future and to take into account the variations in value over time due to the behavior of markets.

The author also seems to be suggesting that financial instruments make the things being traded seem more abstract than the items involved in a simple purchase of hard goods, since he/she mentions the elimination of the need for "shared belief systems or cultural norms". For example, if an investor shorts a stock, he/she is betting that the value will decrease. But this doesn't necessarily mean that the investor wishes the company or the equity markets to fail. The author is suggesting that the transaction is not based on any kind of morals or lack of morals.

So if my reading of the paragraph makes any sense, I think that would make the answer to your question "both". "Ways to reach agreements": shorting, futures, hedging, derivatives, etc. "Agreements on more things": opinions about future performance, trading in a range of commodities, types of real estate, etc.

Comment: It is very detailed and helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In a more pithy style, the heading simply expresses the notion that "the expansion of financial markets has increased social complexity and reduced many more relations to the cash nexus".

I'm not sure there is any clear distinction between "more ways to reach agreements" and "more things on which to come to agreements".

Markets have relatively simple ways of being conducted, and they have not obviously increased the number of things which are subject to trading of any kind. Rather, what markets have dramatically increased is the *amount of trading* which occurs on the same things, they have reduced these trades *to cash*, and they have increased the *remoteness* of potential counterparties to the source of the thing being traded.

In other words, what has increased is not mostly ways to agree or things to agree on, but the sheer volume of cash agreements.